# React: Redirect based on flag: 'redirect' flag should be set to true, yet flag appears false at all times

Tags: reactjs

Quite a large component, but here it is:

```
export default class IssueBrowser extends React.Component {
    static contextType = AppContext

    state = {
        issues: [],
        redirect: false,
        noResponse: false
    }

    render() {
        const NewIssueForm = (props) => {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.createIssue}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                        <input className="form-control" name="title" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="body">Body</label>
                        <textarea name="body" className="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" />
                </form>
            )
        }

        const IssueDetail = (props) => {
            let {id} = useParams()
            let issue = this.state.issues.find(issue => issue.id === id)

            if (issue) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1 className="card-title">{issue.title}</h1>
                        <p className="card-text">{issue.body}</p>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => this.deleteIssue(issue.id)}>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                )
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }

        const IssueListItem = (props) => {
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={props.issue.id}>
                    <Link to={"/issues/" + props.issue.id}>{props.issue.title}</Link>
                </li>
            )
        }

        const IssueList = (props) => {
                if (this.state.issues && this.state.issues.length > 0) {
                    return (
                        <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                            {this.state.issues.map(issue => <IssueListItem key={issue.id} issue={issue} />)}
                        </ul>
                    )
                } else if (!this.state.noResponse) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            There are no issues. Aren't you lucky?
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                return null;
        }

        const MainSwitch = (props) => {
            return (
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/users/registration">
                        <UserRegistration />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path="/issues/create/">
                        <!-- this console.log statement shows false?!??? ->
                        {console.log(this.state.redirect)}
                        {this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
                        <NewIssueForm />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path="/issues/:id">
                        {this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
                        <IssueDetail />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <IssueList />
                    </Route>

                </Switch>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="mt-5">
                <this.Navigation />
                <this.NoResponseFromServer noResponse={this.state.noResponse} />
                <div className="p-3 border border-top-0 rounded-bottom">
                    <MainSwitch />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    deleteIssue = (issue_id) => {
        this.context.setLoading(true)
        this.setState({redirect: true})

        Issues.delete(issue_id)
            .then(response => { 
                this.refreshIssues() 
                this.context.setLoading(false) })

    }

    createIssue = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({redirect: true})
        this.context.setLoading(true)

        let payload = {
            title: event.target.title.value,
            body: event.target.body.value }

        Issues.create(payload)
            .then(response => { 
                this.context.setLoading(false)
                this.refreshIssues() })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) })

    }

    refreshIssues = () => {
        Issues.getAll()
            .then(issues => {
                this.setState({issues}) })
            .catch(error => {
                if (!error.response) { this.setState({noResponse: true}) } })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshIssues()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        // Have to clear redirect flag here. The redirect happens when the HTML
        // is re-rendered, because redirects happen via <Redirect /> tag. but we
        // were clearing the flag before any re-rendering happened, meaning
        // <Redirect /> was never even being rendered in the first place. So
        // after a re-render takes place, check to see if redirect = true, then
        // clear it. Doing it this way gives the <Redirect /> component a chance
        // to be rendered before being cleared.
        if (prevState.redirect) {
            this.setState({redirect: false})
        }
    }


    NoResponseFromServer = (props) => {
        if (this.state.noResponse) {
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                    No response received from server. Is it running?
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    Navigation = (props) => {
        return (
            <nav className="nav nav-tabs">
                <li className="nav-item"><NavLink to="/" exact={true} className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">All</NavLink></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><NavLink to="/issues/create/" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">New</NavLink></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><NavLink to="/users/registration/" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Register</NavLink></li>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem:

I have a redirect flag on this component. If it's set to true, the render method should see that, and render a `<Redirect />`, but it doesn't, and a `{console.log(this.state.redirect)}` statement shows that it is always set to false, even on page re-render.

I'm not sure how react-router-dom redirects work specifically in this case. As you can see, there is a `<Switch>` component inside of this component. So basically it's redirecting to a different `<Route>` inside of `<IssueBrowser>` whenever a redirect happens. The idea here being that, when a user deletes an issue from the list, or creates an issue, they get taken from the issue detail view, or the new issue form view, and then land on the list of all issues after they either submit the form, or delete an issue.

I have no idea why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you will use hook and useEffect instead of building class for that component :D

Consider that :D

Then you will be able to easily change lifecycle for your component. 
P.S. do something like that

```
if(isRedirect){

  return (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  )
}
```

should work